# Clearing the entire android activity stack

Tags: android

Again the same question. How to clear the entire stack of my activity? **Humble suggestion, Read the question before marking it duplicate** 
Now Below is the diagram to give a view of my stack.

[image]

**Initial activity:** Called from NFC tag touch and can be touched at any instance of application running. This is never maintained in stack and gets destroyed, moment new activity starts.

**Startup activity** Called from Initial activity or icon touch. this is alos not maintained in stack and get destroyed moment next activity comes in foreground. But imp cause take decision which activity to start.

**main activity:** This is main activity. start of application and gets destroyed only when app is closed.

Now my problem is at some instance I touch my tag, so after some condition check, I need to remove all the activities from stack before starting my StatupActivity. Hope I have made myself clear. Any query feel free to ask. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is this working for you ntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);?

Comment: don't take me wrong, i'm not trying to argue. but you mentioned "I need to remove all the activities from stack before starting my StatupActivity". can i ask why?

Comment: @MT8. ClearTop will only work when we have some activity in stack. but I dont have any activity in stack. so clear top will not help here

Comment: @JosephusVillarey Actually, when my app is running, in my stack I have MainActivity as primary activity and from there all other activity start. but when NFC tag is touched a new Activity comes up. After some criteria meets, I need to remove all the activity from stack, as if its a fresh launch. So for that I need to remove all activity

Comment: my point is maybe you don't need to. you can code your activities such that they can look as if freshly launched when receiving a new intent. take a look at overriding onNewIntent() on activities.

Comment: Actually that can be done but that will make code cumbersome and difficult to manage and complex. Looking for some simpler solution

Comment: And also, what if on my startup activity user clicks on back. Ideally MainActivity should not come up. But still since it was there in back stake it will come up but I dont want it

Answer (score 0):

okay please read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) link carefully
now set android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" in AndroidManifest in StatupActivity (for your case)

now start your activity with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP Flag

it is work for me i hope you will find help...

Comment: Hey thanx Imtiyaz. Let me try this out

Comment: I was using CLEAR_TASK flag and added ur suggested flag in manifest. But no. its not working. I am getting my main activity still in my activity stack

Comment: have you add android:clearTaskOnLaunch in your AndroidManifest file..?

Comment: Yup. I added that in manifest and also mentioned in prev. comment

Comment: okay now add flag with intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: CLEAR_TOP works when we have to clear the stack of activity above of the starting activity. suppose I launch A then B then C. So ABC will be stack from bottom to up.If I start A with CLEAR_TOP flag from C then every thing will be removed from stack. But if I start C from B with CLEAR_TOP flag, it as good as starting activity without any flag

Comment: so what you want exactly..? you need to clear activity stack or any thing else ..? provide some more detail...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41167/discussion-between-imtiyaz-khalani-and-black-devil)